# Provide Help "Dialog" to Insert Well Formatted Code

Tags: feature-request

I often see code which has a strange indentation. This seems to be a "problem" caused by the four space indentation required. People copy and paste code from the code editor into the edit window, then realise they have to put four spaces in front, but don't add it to all lines evenly.

I would suggest a button "Insert Code...", which opens a form to paste code into it. A "Insert" button at the bottom of the form will insert the code and automatically add the four space indent in front of all lines.

The benefit of this method would be the extensibility:

- There could be a field to ask for the code language. On insert it could check for the language tag and ask if the language tag shall be added.
- There could be a button to style/check the code if required/wished.

It would keep the editor simple, but provide a convenient way to quickly insert code by copy and paste.

The current "Insert code snippet..." is a great way to insert JavaScript code and for sure works for other languages, but I would like to see a more generic approach which is working for all languages.

Answer (score 1):

There already is a button to mark an entire section as code, and that adds spaces to all lines appropriately:

> [image]

Comment: Yes indeed. It would be another suggestion to mention this behaviour in the help text, which would lead more users to use this function. But what about the language tags, and optional code check/styling?

Comment: There is plenty of help text discussing the markdown features, including this one.

Comment: If a user just clicks the button, it will insert a sample code element. The help text just states, code needs four spaces indent, but there is no word about using this button to automatically indent a selected code snippet.

Comment: @Flovdis If you want the help text updated then you should write a proposal for updating the help text.  Currently you're proposing a new feature, rather than a change to the instructions for the existing feature.

Comment: Yes, this topic is not about updating the help text. This would be my plan B.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're saying, and it's not that I disagree with you, I just don't see this being as big of a deal as most make it out to be.

As stated before, there already is a shortcut that allows one to get their code to appear in a code block in the question/answer, but that doesn't do much for their formatting.

The trouble with formatting is that it...varies.  Between languages like C and Java and PHP, you're going to have several different styles of curly brace placement *alone*.  You may run into other scenarios in which the methods are formatted in a way that the return type appears *above* the method name:

```
int*
int_ptr()
{
    // etc
}
```

Then there are languages in which indentation and format **absolutely** matter, like Python.  While the most annoying thing about it has been abstracted out (thanks to HTML, tabs vs spaces is a thing of the past when copying into your terminal), the indentation can be sporadic and vary between blocks (even though it's bad style):

```
def method1():
    if True:
      while True:
       annoyed = raw_input("This indentation is inconsistent.  Annoyed yet? ")
       if annoyed.lower() == 'yes':
               break
```

There's nothing that Stack Overflow can or should do to enforce well-formatted code.  That should be left to the community that wants to volunteer a moment to do a bit of code formatting in their editor of choice.

Comment: I agree, but my request is not to solve all code style problems. I simply would like to see the same kind of comfort of the current JavaScript way to insert code to other languages.

Comment: I suppose I'm not clear on what that "comfort" is.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Flovdis There are two purposes to that tool.  1) because lots of HTML questions involve HTML markup, CSS, and Javascript.  Being able to separate them into different code blocks, all with the appropriate prettify marker is useful. 2) It lets you run the code. 1) Is almost never relevant outside of HTML questions; you're just so rarely working with multiple different programming languages in other contexts 2 is only an option because SE runs in a browser, which already has support for compiling and executing the code in moderate safety; that's not an option in pretty much all other languages.

Comment: If you use the "Code snippet" button, there is an editor to insert the code in it's original form. After inserting this code, it is marked as code snippet and a language tag added. One can easily edit this code snippet and there is a "Tidy" button to apply code styling if one wishes to do that. Why this is only working for JavaScript, I personally miss a more generic approach which works for other languages as well.

Comment: @Servy This is true, still, editing code in it's original form is some comfort. Also a quick way to add some code styling, even to understand posted code is a benefit.